Clone entire uniswap v3
Hope everyone is doing great.
I need to clone a uniswap v3 entirely but can't find a good resource to achieve what I want.
Has anyone prior deployed the uniswap v3 clone if yes.
Any small bit of guidance would be much appreciated .
Also any documentation other than uniswaps explaining the contracts used in v3 and there functionality

I recommend reading the Uniswap V3 Documentation for a comprehensive overview. You can also check out the Uniswap V3 Development Book for more insights
If you want a deeper understanding of V3, consider exploring its Whitepaper

Thanks for a valuable response earlier now i had one more question as well because I'm going to deploy the clone on L2 based on L2 base chain. In that scenario could you enlighten me about the governance contracts. Because I'm deploying on separate chain so I guess I don't need them
